# User Entry required and submit button script

Tags: javascript, livecycle, submit-button

I have a number of text fields that I require to have entries. I also have a script with the email submit button that hides some items and makes others read-only. But when the button is clicked, the unfilled text fields are highlighted, but have also been made read-only so that no entry can be made. Is there a way to delay the script I have for the submit button until everything has been completed?

```
form1.#pageSet[0].Page1.Email::mouseUp - (JavaScript, client)
    this.presence = "invisible";
    Print.presence = "invisible";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.PartName.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Description.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Material.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Layout.SeeAttached.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Layout.Number.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Layout.Spacing.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Types.Tool.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Types.Cut.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Types.Press.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.Explain.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.TolQuan.Tolerance.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.RequiredItems.Table1.Row1.Col2.TolQuan.Quantity.access = "readOnly";
    RFQ.Body.Additional.AdditionalInfo.access = "readOnly";
```

For what it's worth, the fields that require entries are: Material, Number, Tool, Press, Tolerance and Quantity.

Comment: What is your target version of reader? And the XFA version?

Comment: Target Reader version is 8.1. XFA I couldn't tell you, but I'm using ES 8.2.